How to prove that someone forged my signature on a contract that I was not aware of
How to prove that someone forged my signature on a contract that I was not aware of using DocuSign and a Per-Selected Style signature

it is different in that I did  not sign it nor did another person with a pen, but rather the person used a pre selected signature

@MoniqueBalboa How did this other person gain access to the DocuSign document in order to sign it?

There are legal aspects to this question, but I think there are also technical aspects.  I have asked a question about them, referencing this question, on security.SE where such answers would be on topic.

You may want to look at this answer.  I think it says you do not need to prove anything, the burden of proof is on them as Docusign signitures are in the class "those for which signatures are reputed worthless unless a positive proof of attribution to the alleged signer is shown".

This question is similar to: How do you prove a fact at issue in litigation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The most obvious option is to testify under oath that you didn't sign it. Sworn testimony is admissible evidence, even when it comes from a party to a dispute.
Other potential evidence very much depends on the specific facts and circumstances involved, which might tend to show that you didn't sign it.

You can try contacting Docusign for assistance. They can probably provide logs showing the IP address that was used when using that pre-selected signature, and the time this occurred. From that you should be able to determine the ISP, and they may be able to provide corresponding customer information. If the other party is a customer of that ISP and you're not, this would corroborate your claim that they forged your signature.
I'd expect a lawyer with experience in online forgery cases to know these things.

Isn't this information already included with the image of the signature?

I don't know, I've never been on the receiving end of a docusign, only on the signing end.

@bdb484 it is somewhere in the signature, but you can ask for technical assistance in how to find the information.

I went to the bank and the fraud department gave me a printout of the IP address and transaction taht they had.  I tracked the IP and it was Comcast which was our network.  The person who did this is my soon to be ex husband who has not worked for 10 years and bought this toy without sharing with me that he signed a loan under my name. The interesting fact is that he used a mobile device to sign his name yet, used a pre selected signature to sign mine. I don't even know how to do that. He also had our gmails attached to each other so he could see my calendar and I could see his.
